# Statistic result of run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, junit, eclipse-plugin

I develop a Eclipse plugin to create my own 'Run Configuration'. The configuration will call a outside program and print the console the result of running. "Program finished without errors" ==> no error, "Program finished without 6 warnings and 3 errors" ==> 6 warning + 3 errors

When I run a lot of configurations, the result show in separate console and difficult to review.

[image]

**I want to add new tab next Console tab to statistic the result of running configurations based on text output of each console.**

How can I do it? How about 'Unit test' implement way?

Comment: It appears to me, that you are using a normal logger with a ConsoleAppender. Maybe you leave that idea behind and introduce a custom view (based on the existing ConsoleView) and pipe your Log-Output to that particular view.

Comment: @pimpf0r: Thanks for your answer but can you describe your solution clearly?

Comment: If you ask more clearly I can easily explain more clearly. Until then you might want to read about using the view-extension here: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html or here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

Comment: Ok, I got it, Thanks.